# How can I route SYN and RELATED TCP 80,443 out a different interface than my default GW?

Tags: linux, route

I have a server with two nics (`eth0 = 10.10.10.1/24`, `eth1 = 192.168.1.2/24`). `eth0` is the default route for both local and internet traffic.  I'd like to route anything which is not `10.10.10.x` traffic (eg: `apt` traffic to security.ubuntu.com, us.archive.ubuntu.com or similar repo) out interface `eth1` (which is connected to a linux box doing IP forwarding along with running NTOP).

`security.ubuntu.com` is behind five IP addresses on a `91.189.x.x` subnet so I've tried adding a route with `ip route add 91.189.0.0/16 via 192.168.1.2` but this only appears (via `tcpdump` on the linux router) to create a lot of `ARP` traffic looking for the `91.189.x.x` IP addresses:

```
11:39:32.945343 ARP, Request who-has 91.189.88.149 tell 192.168.1.2,length 46
11:39:33.943867 ARP, Request who-has 91.189.88.149 tell 192.168.1.2,length 46
11:39:34.943893 ARP, Request who-has 91.189.88.149 tell 192.168.1.2,length 46
11:39:35.943977 ARP, Request who-has 91.189.88.149 tell 192.168.1.2,length 46
11:39:35.944108 ARP, Request who-has 91.189.88.161 tell 192.168.1.2,length 46
11:39:36.943903 ARP, Request who-has 91.189.88.149 tell 192.168.1.2,length 46
11:39:36.943917 ARP, Request who-has 91.189.88.161 tell 192.168.1.2,length 46
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Needed to use the IP address of the upstream Linux router, not my local IP, on the `eth1` interface (eg: `192.168.1.1` instead of `.2`)

`ip route add 91.189.0.0/16 via 192.168.1.1`

Comment: While this fixes your immediate problem, you will have to add a new route every time you want to access a new address space on the Internet in this manner. @joeqwerty is correct: you should set your default gateway to 192.168.1.1. If the machine you SSH from is on the 10.10.10.0/24 network off eth0, then you should have no problem accessing your server. If the machine you SSH from is not on the 10.10.10.0/24 network, you should set up a route to THAT network via eth0.

Answer (score 1):

Set the Default Gateway on your 192.168.1.2 interface. The 10.10.10.1 interface needs no DG and will communicate directly with everything else on the 10.10.10.0/24 network. All 192.168.1.0/24 traffic as well as all non-local traffic will go out the 192.168.1.2 interface.

Comment: I am using the gateway on `10.10.10.1` to ssh into the machine. Wouldn't changing the DG to `eth1` then require connecting over the `eth1` network for ssh access? IIRC, I tried that earlier in the week and could not connect to the machine as I normally would.  Not sure if I botched the command, or what.